# For loop in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to list every card in a deck of cards (along with a number assigned to the card) using this code:

```
suitName = ("hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs")
rankName = ("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King")

def translate():
    rank = ""
    suit = ""
    cards = ""
    cardNum = 0

    for x in rankName:
        rank = x

    for y in suitName:
        suit = y

    for i in range(0, NUMCARDS):
        cards += rank
        cards += " of "
        cards += suit
        cardNum = i
        i += 1

        print cardNum
        print "    "
        print cards
```

My output is only getting "King of clubs" 52 times though. What do I need to do?

Comment: Ah, the joys of indentation levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loops should be nested, but right now they just execute in order. Right now, `rank` goes through all `rankName`s and gets set to the last one, `suit` goes through all `suitName`s and gets set to the last one, and then they're printed out 52 times.

You shouldn't even really have that last loop.

```
suitName = ("hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs")
rankName = ("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King")

def translate():
    cardNum = 0

    for x in rankName:
        rank = x

        for y in suitName:
            suit = y

            cards = ""
            cards += rank
            cards += " of "
            cards += suit
            i += 1

            print cardNum
            print "    "
            print cards
```

Also, `rank = x` and `suit = y` could just be `for rank in rankName:` and `for suit in suitName`. Also also, pre-initializing the variables isn't really useful.

Comment: Never mind, I figure it out. Set the cardNum to += 1 instead.

Answer (score 3):

There are built-in methods for accomplishing what you want as well.

```
import itertools

suitName = ("hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs")
rankName = ("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King")

cross_product = itertools.product(rankName, suitName)

for card_num, (rank, suit) in enumerate(cross_product, start=1):
  print("{0}    {1} of {2}".format(card_num, rank, suit))
```

Comment: im afraid that this is not cleaner than two simple for loops, quite the opposite is the case IMO

Comment: @Paranix `intertools.product` and `enumerate` are encapsulated, generic versions of the for loops. You should read up on them, as they much easier to understand if you know them.